# EditText is not filtering the list of RecyclerView in Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to filter the list in RecyclerView by EditText. In Activity, passing the response in the adapter object, which is getting from the ViewModel class. And in the adapter, the filter method is written. Overall the Search Filter from EditText is not working. Below the code is written I am not sure how can I resolve this problem.

Project having manly an Activity,Adapter, XML file, and the ViewModel class.

**fragment_availabletender**

**This page is having EditText & RecyclerView.**

```
         <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editMobileNo"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:padding="0dp"
         android:background="@drawable/login_edittext"
         android:ems="10"
         android:hint="Search Tender"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_3_24"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tendertext"
         android:paddingLeft="50dp"
         >
       </EditText>

       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tender_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:color="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />
```

**Model Class
This class is having model**

```
   data class TenderProperty(

    val id: String,
    @Json(name = "img_src") val imgSrcUrl: String,
    val type: String,
    val price: Double
    )
```

**ViewModel**
**Here response is getting**

```
class NotificationViewModel : ViewModel() {


val response: LiveData<List<TenderProperty>>
    get() = _response

private var _responseByArray = ArrayList<TenderProperty>()
val responseByArray: List<TenderProperty>
    get() = _responseByArray

private val _navigateToSelectedProperty = MutableLiveData<TenderProperty>()
val navigateToSelectedProperty: LiveData<TenderProperty>
    get() = _navigateToSelectedProperty

// Create a Coroutine scope using a job to be able to cancel when needed
private var viewModelJob = Job()

private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main )


init {
    getTenderRealEstateProperties()
}

private fun getTenderRealEstateProperties() {

    coroutineScope.launch {
        // Get the Deferred object for our Retrofit request
        var getPropertiesDeferred = TenderApi.retrofitService.getProperties()
        try {
            // this will run on a thread managed by Retrofit
            val listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()

            _responseByArray= listResult as ArrayList<TenderProperty>

           Log.d("respbyary",responseByArray.toString())

        } catch (e: Exception) {

            _response.value = ArrayList()
            Log.d("class",responseByArray.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Adapter class**

```
class ListTenderAdapter(context: Context, var tender: List<TenderProperty>) : ListAdapter<TenderProperty, ListTenderAdapter.TenderPropertyViewHolder>(DiffCallback),Filterable {

var originalData=tender

var filteredData = ArrayList<TenderProperty>()

//dought22
class TenderPropertyViewHolder(private var binding: TenderListViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(tenderProperty: TenderProperty) {
        binding.property = tenderProperty
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}

companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TenderProperty>()
{
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TenderProperty, newItem: TenderProperty): Boolean {
        return oldItem === newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TenderProperty, newItem: TenderProperty): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TenderPropertyViewHolder {
    return TenderPropertyViewHolder(TenderListViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TenderPropertyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val tenderProperty = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(tenderProperty)
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {

    return object : Filter() {

        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

            var filteredList = ArrayList<TenderProperty>()
            if (constraint.isNullOrBlank()) {
                filteredData.addAll(originalData)
            }
            else {
                for (data in originalData) {
                    if (
                        data.id.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())||
                        data.price.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())||
                        data.type.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        filteredList.add(data)
                    } }
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = filteredList
            return filterResults
        }
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {

            filteredData.clear()
            filteredData.addAll(results.values as ArrayList<TenderProperty>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }}}
```

**This is the Activity**

```
 class TenderListActivity:AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var adapter: ListTenderAdapter
lateinit var search:EditText
private lateinit var binding: FragmentAvailabletenderBinding
private val viewModel: NotificationViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationViewModel::class.java)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_availabletender)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<FragmentAvailabletenderBinding>(
        this,
        R.layout.fragment_availabletender
    )

    search = binding.editMobileNo

    val divider = DividerItemDecoration(applicationContext, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
    binding.tenderList.addItemDecoration(divider)

    setupRecyclerView()
    initViewModel()
    search()
    backButton()
}

private fun setupRecyclerView() {

    binding.tenderList.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(5))
    adapter = ListTenderAdapter(this, viewModel.responseByArray)
    binding.tenderList.setAdapter(adapter)

}

private fun initViewModel() {
    viewModel.response.observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    })

}

private fun backButton()
{
    binding.backbtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val backbtn: Intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(backbtn)

    })
}

private fun search()
{
       search.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString())

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

        }
    })
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm  not use the filter in the adapter,but i think may be u can use the list.filter and setThe NewData with the DiffUtil? although it may be not the best solution

Comment: While writing list. filter, It is getting an error.

Comment: i mean the data.filter not the recycleview.filter . use the filter to filter the data what you want .then reset the data and notify

Comment: I used the filter but it is not working, maybe the problem is somewhere else.In below comment I the filter code what I added.

Comment: **else {
                    originalData.filter {
                        it.id.contains(queryString) ||
                                it.imgSrcUrl.contains(queryString) ||
                                it.price.toString().contains(queryString)
                    }
                    filteredData.addAll(originalData)
                }**